# Subversion SVN version used for TortoiseSVN 1.6.x

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am stuck with an old version of Tortoise SVN 1.6.16. The context menu handlers are so slow in this version and would like to work with commandline as much as possible. Unfortunately the installation folder doesn't contain any svn.exe. Which version of Subversion will be compatible with the TortoiseSVN version I am using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is part of a [FAQ of TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#multiclients),:

> The version of the Subversion library that TortoiseSVN uses is
>   indicated in the filename of the installer, other clients have similar
>   indications. You have to make sure that those versions match each
>   other in the first two digits. For example, all clients using
>   Subversion 1.6.x can be used together (the 'x' indicates that this
>   number is not relevant for compatibility)

So, you can use any SVN 1.6.x, or 1.6.16 if want to be extra careful about compatibility.

Comment: Thanks I am on Silk-SVN 1.6.16 the code base is too large. so can't take risks... Really fed up with lockouts